# C# create User ODBC without administrator permission

Tags: c#, .net, dns, odbc

I create odbc from c# code using code below:

```
string ODBC_PATH = "SOFTWARE\\ODBC\\ODBC.INI\\"; 
string driverName = "SQL Server";
string dsnName = "DSNName";
string database = "DBName";
string description = "Description";
string server = "Server";
bool trustedConnection = false;
string driverPath = "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\sqlsrv32.dll"; 

var datasourcesKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(ODBC_PATH + "ODBC Data Sources");         
if (datasourcesKey == null) 
{
    throw new Exception("ODBC Registry key does not exist"); 
}        
datasourcesKey.SetValue(dsnName, driverName);          
var dsnKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(ODBC_PATH + dsnName);        
if (dsnKey == null) 
{
    throw new Exception("DSN was not created"); 
}        

dsnKey.SetValue("Database", database);         
dsnKey.SetValue("Description", description);         
dsnKey.SetValue("Driver", driverPath);         
dsnKey.SetValue("LastUser", "sa");         
dsnKey.SetValue("Server", server);         
dsnKey.SetValue("Database", database);
dsnKey.SetValue("username", "sa");
dsnKey.SetValue("password", "sa");
dsnKey.SetValue("Trusted_Connection", trustedConnection ? "Yes" : "No");
```

But above code create “System DNS”. I would like create “User DNS” without requires administrator permission.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do some steps:

- First Turn off your `UAC`
- Then Include a `UAC` manifest in your executable
- Finally launch your app as administrator (`Run as Administrator`)

**Based on MSDN**:

> Visual Studio® provides the capability to automatically embed an XML application manifest file within the resource section of the Portable Executable (PE) image. This section addresses how to use Visual Studio to create a signed PE image containing an application manifest. This application manifest can therefore include the necessary requestedExecutionLevel attributes, allowing the application to run with the desired privilege level on Windows Vista. When the program is launched, the application manifest information will be extracted from the resource section of the PE and used by the operating system. It is not necessary to use the Visual Studio graphical user interface (GUI) to include a manifest. Once the necessary changes are in the source code, compiling and linking using command-line tools will also include the application manifest in the resulting PE image.
>
> Manifest File
>   To mark your application with a requestedExecutionLevel, first create an application manifest file to use with the target application. This file can be created by using any text editor. The application manifest file should have the same name as the target executable file with a .manifest extension. 
>   For example: `IsUserAdmin.exe.manifest`

**Example:**

```
Executable: IsUserAdmin.exe 
Manifest:IsUserAdmin.exe.manifest
Sample application manifest file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0"> 
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0"
     processorArchitecture="X86"
     name="IsUserAdmin"
     type="win32"/> 
  <description>Description of your application</description> 
  <!-- Identify the application security requirements. -->
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel
          level="requireAdministrator"
          uiAccess="false"/>
        </requestedPrivileges>
       </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. However, I still don't know how to  create “User DNS”